# Change product view magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

We have a magento store with the magestore auction module installed.
When we click a category it still loads the theme/catalog/product/list.phtml instead of theme/auction/list.phtml

I have tried copy pasting the code from the auction template to another , this didn't suffice since it still got it's _productCollection from the Local/Mage/Catalog/Block/List.php instead of Local/MageStore/Auction/Block/List.php ... which doesn't have the right filters etc.

Any idea how i should solve this ?

Comment: in the construct of your auction block echo something - does it load?
If yes then in your construct echo $this->getTemplate(), does that match with the path to the template file?
If yes, go to your template file and enter "<h1>Hello</h1>", does that load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are your theme directories structured?  In case it looks like app/design/frontend//default or so and your Auction extensions design files are not in base, you may need to copy some of its contents to your template directory.

Try first copying the following directories to your theme folder:

**app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/auction-extension.xml**

This file takes care of showing theme/auction/list.phtml instead of theme/catalog/product/list.phtml

**app/design/frontend/default/default/template/auction-extension**

The reason why it just displays the default list.phtml instead of your auction's list.phtml